# The dots on the wall

Tags: visual, steganography

So when I was visiting *Tsukuba International Conference Center* in Tsukuba, Japan, I saw these dots on the wall of its big conference hall.

At first, I thought the dots were seemingly placed randomly, but later I realized there is something hidden in there. Try to find it!

[image: The dots on the wall]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right column repeats:

> \begin{array}{cccc} 16&2&13&3\\ 9&7&12&6\\ 4&14&1&15\\ 5&11&8&10 \end{array}

every 4, and is:

> a magic square summing to $34$.

The left column:

> \begin{array}{cccc} 2&11&8&13\\ 16&5&10&3\\ 9&4&15&6\\ 7&14&1&12 \end{array}

also:

> a magic square summing to $34$.

In fact, they are both:

> [most-perfect magic squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most-perfect_magic_square)